# A free tool that is capable of selecting questions from a pool and shuffle them randomly?

Tags: teaching, exams

I will be conducting exams, and I need a tool that can let me shuffle and select random , small questions from a pre-defined question pool. My questions are typically matched and complete.

It would be ideal if I can export to word after that. Any idea or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Easy to do in excel - had 5 banks of 5 questions and a quiz page that took 1 at random from each bank... Formatted and printed directly from excel - each quiz was A5 sized...

Comment: I am a programmer.  A proper (uniform) shuffle is Fisher Yates.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use [ClassMarker](https://www.classmarker.com/), which is a great tool for creating a quiz with random questions.

You can choose questions you select and randomize the order of the selected questions, randomize answer options or [add randomly selected questions](https://www.classmarker.com/online-testing/manual/#autoquestions), so each time the quiz is taken, different questions will be pulled from your question pool.

Also, the option of exporting the tests to word is available.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried it but It don't provide a good shuffling nor a good way to export

Comment: @Omar113 Also this discussion may help: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/11384

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [solution in java script](https://codepen.io/southface/pen/mExOGA) that runs in the browser or wherever you like.

Here is a "[random choice generator](https://www.textfixer.com/tools/random-choice.php)".

And here is a "[random name picker](https://www.classtools.net/random-name-picker/)". You could give your questions short names and draw them according to where the wheel stops.

In Emacs, you could also write each question on a line and use this [elisp function to randomize the order of lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172054/how-can-i-random-sort-lines-in-a-buffer). Then export it to word, LaTeX, whatever, with [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/). That's my favorite.

Finally, here is my [google search](https://www.google.at/search?q=random%20picker).

Comment: Some good pointers and useful info in this answer...

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps a bit orthogonal, but you could ask a colleague in Computer Science to have students build you such a tool as a class project. If you have the time to spend to specify exactly what you want, you could get the perfect tool. In addition, the students involved will get valuable programming experience as well as experience in working to the specifications of a client.

This isn't a massive undertaking, actually.

The downside is that you need to wait for it to be built, but in the meantime you can also think about what features you most desire. It may be possible for a group of students to build the core functionality quite quickly.

Comment: I think it would be just a few lines script in Python to pull a random portion from a list of questions.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer, yes, the core is pretty simple. It sounds to me like a good project for first year programming students.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer That might be easy for someone named "*Programmer," but we have no idea what Omar teaches and whether he's ever even touched Python.

Comment: @AzorAhai I didn’t say Omar should write this by himself. I just said if someone has a bit programming experience it should not be too difficult and it could be applied to even first year computer science undergrads.

Comment: @AzorAhai besides my comment you could argue to this answer : https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/117916/98164 that by default it is assumed the questioner is fluent with Java script or other programming stuffs.

Comment: @alone Yes, that's is true